# how to proof $(e^x - 1) \log(1 + x) \gt x^2$ when $x\gt 1$

Tags: real-analysis

I have tried to caculate the function's limit for 4th,but it is always $0$ at $0$,so I don't know how to cope with it.do I need to limit it for another time or there is some other ways easier. Thanks.

Comment: What does mean *"the function's limit for 4th"* ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1756618/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2750387/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/620316/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(e%5Ex%20-%201)%20%5Clog(1%20%2B%20x)%20%5Cgt%20x%5E2%24)

Comment: I make a new function f(x)=(e^x-1)log(1+x)-x^2and give the derivative evolution sorry I wrote it  limit